# Start two infinite Python scripts from GUI on Windows

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, batch-file

I'm trying to start two Python scripts that will run in an infinite loop.

The first script scrapes a webpage and dumps it into a CSV file.
The second script reads that CSV file and displays it on a webpage through Dash (localhost webserver).

With everything I've tried so far, it will run one script and wait for it to end before running the next (which doesn't work for me).

The only thing that has worked for me so far (which isn't optimal for production) is opening two Command Prompts and manually running each script in separate windows.

I've tried two buttons in PyQt.

I've tried a simple batch script (I'm on a Windows7 machine) with structure:

`python file1.py &
python file2.py &`

The functionality I need:
"Whilst the first script is scraping and dumping the web page, the other is at the same time reading and displaying it."

Comment: Does [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)`"" [/B] python file?.py` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `start` to launch both commands:

```
@echo off

start /b python file1.py
start /b python file2.py
```

A few notes about this:  The commands will launch, but will not block the exit of the batch file, so unless you'll need to keep the command prompt open.  Also, to kill them, use `Ctrl`-`Break` to stop the background processes.

It might be cleaner to use Python's `multiprocessing` to run the scripts, either as part of one of the scripts, or with a wrapper script, but that depends on your exact needs.

Comment: I'm using multiprocessing within one of the scripts. If I understand correctly that means I can't use it for this purpose?

Comment: You can absolutely use multiprocessing to accomplish more than one thing in the same script.  Something simple `multiprocessing.Process(target=secondScript, args=(val1, val2)).start()` might be enough to launch the second script from the first.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to run `file2.py` after `file1.py` is completely finished its job?
If so, you can replace & with && so it would be something like this:

```
python file1.py && python file2.py
```

Comment: The question was specific, if not a little difficult to understand for non native English speakers, "so far, it will run one script and wait for it to end before running the next (which doesn't work for me)", means that they're wanting both to run infinitely and at the same time. Whilst the first script is scraping and dumping the web page, the other is at the same time reading and displaying it.

Comment: @Compo That's exactly right. I apologize for not being clear.